# how to use bootstrap button in Url. Action with asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

what is the correct way to use bootstrap button with thw Url. Action.

```
 @Url.Action("Delete", "Delete", null, new { id = item.Id }),new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-xs" })
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with this code ?

Comment: if there is a problem with this code, probably is reference the to `bootstrap.css`

Comment: it shows that argument 5 : cannot convert from <anonymous type of= id to system web MVC ajax option

Comment: I answer your question...you're probably using the wrong helper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I think you're using the wrong helper. What you want probably is [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "your action", "your controller", new { id = item.Id },new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-xs" })
```

if you still want to use Url.Action, just use like this

```
<a href="@Url.Action("your action", "your controller", new { id = item.Id }" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Delete</a>
```

Comment: @ElmerDantas in your ActionLink sample, the parenthesis before the last `new` keyword is wrong and must be removed in order to make the code work.