# How to call a method with a button in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, button

I'm trying to simply call a void type method from a controller named "ButtonController", with a button in my index.cshtml file. I tried that, but it didn't work:

`<button type="button"  onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Click", "ButtonController")'">Button</button>`

Comment: Why would you even use location.href?

Comment: "but it didn't work" What happens instead? Also, view source to check the rendered html to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: @向洪林 don't really know... just did a quick search and find out that location.href. i'm still learning about mvc and asp.net

Comment: @Jasen it wasn't able to find the "ButtonController/Click".

Comment: Anything which is rendered in the view is client side and everything written in controller is server side.. so you can not simply call controller action method directly from client side button click.... You need to have controller action method which will return some response and then you need to call that via http using AJAX...

Answer (score 0):

See [how to use bootstrap button in Url. Action with asp.net mvc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369835/how-to-use-bootstrap-button-in-url-action-with-asp-net-mvc5)

Just you can use one of two alternatives.

```cs
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Botton")">Go to button</a>
@Html.ActionLink("Go to botton", "Index", "Botton")
```

Using a Button is like using Ajax as described by [@chetan-ranpariya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884101/chetan-ranpariya)